# How to properly encrypt/decrypt parts or whole logs?

Tags: vb.net, logging, encryption, nlog

I am looking for advice and best practice in encrypting parts/whole logs in various formats (say JSON or CSV). I have 0 experience in encrypting anything.

*(Disclaimer - I am using Nlog so if you have experience in that library, it would be great to get insight but I am also asking for general ideas/practices/processes.)*

I want to encrypt and then decrypt parts of my logs, for example stack trace, user name and other minor things, while keeping other parts of logs untouched (they could be encrypted but there is no need). How to do that? Should I encrypt part of my logs, whole logs or whole files?

How common is it to encrypt logs? How should it be done? Using specific parts of a library to do the encryption or simply encrypting a string before passing it to the logger? How do you manage decrypting the logs after? Without encryption I can simply import my logs from JSON or CSV to Excel and do everything, but when parts of them are encrypted it complicates the process.

How do you organize the decryption process? Where/how do you decrypt? Is encrypting/decrypting resource intensive process, which might affect performance of a logging library?

Questions are rather basic but I am a novice programmer and I have not found answers on SO or other sites. Encrypting logs seems like an "odd thing".

Many thanks for all help.

Comment: Your question is far too broad for SO. If you want to learn about encryption then go and learn about encryption. There's plenty of information out there. You can come back here when you have a specific question, which is what SO is for.

Comment: Never needed to encrypt logs, and never seen a case where it's needed.  For example, even the Windows Security log isn't encrypted after all.   Question would be why is encrypting logs even needed?  What type of events are you logging?

Comment: I was thinking about encrypting for example stack trace or some messages. Since I am a newbie I am trying to get my head around it. I thought that perhaps somebody is doing it on a daily basis and would like to share best practice

Comment: This is also called masking/obfuscation. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/4091#issuecomment-837077594 (I guess you could implement masking/obfuscation that can be reversed when having the right "key")